# Nativescript-Dev-Appium Setup

Tags: appium, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to implement nativescript-dev-appium in an existing nativescript-angular project and am having a lot of trouble getting the plugin configured.

The simulator appears to be found but the run fails in the `before all` and `after all` hooks because it appears to not have a device instance.

```
walrus:demo-appium niirds$ npm run e2e -- --runType sim.iPhoneX --verbose

> @ e2e /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium
> node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts  "--runType" "sim.iPhoneX" "--verbose"



/Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json
Capabilities found at: /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json 
Appium will use default automation name
Available applications:  ["platforms/ios/build/emulator/demoappium.app"]
Pick first application:   "platforms/ios/build/emulator/demoappium.app"
Application full path: /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/platforms/ios/build/emulator/demoappium.app 
Found devices:  [ { token: 'C8B1990E-1593-49A8-AA68-C7E5CC2134BB',
    name: 'iPhone X',
    status: 'booted',
    type: 'watch',
    apiLevel: '12.2',
    platform: 'ios',
    config: { density: 3, offsetPixels: 87 } } ]
  1) "before all" hook: start server
  2) "after all" hook: stop server

  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) "before all" hook: start server:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
      at DeviceManager.<anonymous> (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/lib/device-manager.js:82:28)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/lib/device-manager.js:4:58)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

  2) "after all" hook: stop server:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'platform' of undefined
      at Function.<anonymous> (node_modules/mobile-devices-controller/lib/device-controller.js:104:24)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/node_modules/mobile-devices-controller/lib/device-controller.js:7:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules/mobile-devices-controller/lib/device-controller.js:3:12)
      at Function.uninstallApp (node_modules/mobile-devices-controller/lib/device-controller.js:103:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/index.js:85:64)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/index.js:7:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/index.js:3:12)
      at Object.stopServer (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/index.js:77:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (e2e/setup.js:16:37)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /Users/niirds/mobi/demo-appium/e2e/setup.js:7:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (e2e/setup.js:3:12)
      at Context.after (e2e/setup.js:15:28)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23)



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ e2e: `node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts  "--runType" "sim.iPhoneX" "--verbose"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the simulator capability, provided by the installation:

```
    "sim.iPhoneX": {
        "platformName": "iOS",
        "platformVersion": "/12*/",
        "deviceName": "iPhone X",
        "noReset": false,
        "fullReset": false,
        "app": ""
    },
```

I have xcode 10.2 installed, and here is the package.json if that helps.

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.demoappium",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.3.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "e2e": "node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts ",
    "e2e-watch": "tsc -p e2e --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.2.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/chai": "~4.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "~5.2.5",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "mocha": "~5.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "~1.18.0",
    "mocha-multi": "~1.0.1",
    "nativescript-dev-appium": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.9.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.21.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "6ccaee804c71761be1c2f91d0b2dd67c8ba6d2b6",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Steps to reproduce:
1. create sample nativescript-angular app--i used the tab navigation one for this test.
2. install nativescript-dev-appium: `npm i -D nativescript-dev-appium`
3. install other dependencies https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/testing/end-to-end-testing/overview#environment-setup
4. build app: `tns build <platform>`
5. run test: `npm run e2e -- --runType

i have been trying to get this to work on iOS for now.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you verify your environment setup by running the tests on the [sample app](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/tree/master/demo/AngularApp)? Do you have a Github sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: yes, the code i posted is from the angular tab sample app. i can add steps to reproduce to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for some reason the device type that device controller has returned `type: 'watch'` is not correct.

I suggest you change the config to something like:

```
"sim.iPhoneX": {
    "platformName": "iOS",
    "platformVersion": "12.2",
    "deviceName": "iPhone X",
    "noReset": false,
    "fullReset": false,
    "app": ""
},
```

or simply try it with the `--ignoreDeviceController` option.

Comment: many thanks! the `ignoreDeviceController` option definitely helped appium to find the device and i did have to change the installation versions from "/12*/" to "12.2". though i found that i had to start an appium server using the desktop app, and start the simulator before i start the test--neither one starts from the test. can you tell me if i might have some configuration setup wrong? i thought that the appium server and the simulator should be started by the plugin?